# methods from model to select in erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my model `Acte` I have this code :

```
def aut_complet_un
    unless auteur_un_lieu  ==""
        auteur_un_autorite + " de " + auteur_un_lieu + ", " + auteur_un_nom 
    else
        auteur_un_autorite + ", " + auteur_un_nom
    end
end

def aut_complet_deux
    unless auteur_deux_lieu  ==""
        auteur_deux_autorite + " " + auteur_deux_lieu + " " + auteur_deux_nom
    else
        auteur_deux_autorite + ", " + auteur_deux_nom
    end
end
```

When I do this in my erb.html :

```
<%= f.select :acte, Acte.all.collect {|s| s.aut_complet_un}, include_blank: true %>
```

However, this is extremely inefficient as Acte contains full (and long) text colums so putting the entirety of the actes into a Hash and then get only the necessary methods seems not efficient.

How do I

1/ fetch only aut_complet_un and aut_complet_deux in the erb.html (in other words, get rid of the .all method) and

2/ merge the two distinctly ? `aut_complet_un + aut_complet_deux` is not the right solution and then I get in one select option the combination of both, rather than each in an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`1/ fetch only aut_complet_un and aut_complet_deux in the erb.html (in other words, get rid of the .all method)`

You can use `select` to only select the relevant columns from the database. This is not the methods `aut_complet_un` and `aut_complet_deux`, but the columns that these methods rely on eg:

```
Acte.select(:auteur_un_autorite, :auteur_un_lieu, :auteur_un_nom).all.map(&:aut_complet_un)
Acte.select(:auteur_deux_autorite, :auteur_deux_lieu, :auteur_deux_nom).all.map(&:aut_complet_deux)
```

Note: the `map` syntax is just a shorter way of writing the same thing as your collect.

The select means that only those columns are returned - ignoring any of the other, larger ones.

However... before you assume that this is what is causing it to be slow... have you looked at whether your table is huge or you have the right indexes on them? these can also cause huge slow-downs... :)

`2/ merge the two distinctly ? aut_complet_un + aut_complet_deux is not the right solution and then I get in one select option the combination of both, rather than each in an option.`

I am unclear what you actually want from this? Do you want two select boxes? One to choose `_un` and one to choose `_deux` ? or one select box with a list of both? If the latter, then you could use something like this:

```
class Acte
  # you'll think of a better name for this...
  def self.select_options   
    options = self.select(:auteur_un_autorite, :auteur_un_lieu, :auteur_un_nom).all.map(&:aut_complet_un)
    options += self.select(:auteur_deux_autorite, :auteur_deux_lieu, :auteur_deux_nom).all.map(&:aut_complet_deux)
    options
  end
```

This in your erb you can use:

```
<%= f.select :acte, Acte.select_options, include_blank: true %>
```